# Cucumber-groovy: practical difference between World{} and World={}?

Tags: groovy, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I am using cucumber-groovy. During development, I often run a single feature. Everything was fine when I have only one step definition groovy file. Now I have two such groovy files, both of which have this block:

```
World {
}
```

Then when I run cucumber with both groovy files in the glue path, I get this error:
`cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: World is already set`

However, when I change the block above to

```
World = {
}
```

everything is working again. So, my question is: is this approach a good solution or a common practice when using cucumber-groovy? Are there any caveats I should be aware of? One thing I can think of is that this approach practically wipes out whatever settings the World might have in other step definitions.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try to use World() { }.
You might missing the parenthese.

Comment: What does this mean? Looks like defining a method, except without return type

Comment: I have no clue about Cucumber but according to groovy syntax `World {}` is invocation of method named _World_ with closure as an argument. `World = { }` is value assignment, which is closure, to the variable named _World_.